# VSTS returns Bad Request, when specifying changeset for build

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using **VSTS** for my **Nightly/CI** builds.

**VSTS** pulls the code from **TFS** repository.

I noticed that triggering the build against (specific changeset E.g.'33333', 'C33333') returns

```
"BadRequest 400 The value specified for SourceVersion is not a valid version spec." 

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.BuildRequestValidationFailedException
```

When changeset is not specified everything works fine. 
Did anyone had this problem?

Comment: How do you let VSTS pulls the code from TFS repository? Do you use external git? https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/repository. How do you specify mapping in repository? Is the changeset (33333) existing?

Comment: Build worked fine with different changesets till yesterday. Right now it does not even start. I get javascript alert with "Source Version is not valid" message

Comment: How do you configure VSTS pulls the code from TFS repository?

Comment: Based on the article external tfs is used for release. How do you use it for build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a request to Microsoft.
They know about this bug. This issue will be fixed this week.

Answer (score 0):

You mean Team Foundation Version Control repository type. Based on my test with VSTS, I can reproduce that issue, the same as REST API.

You can vote this feedback (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3102566/specifying-a-source-version-in-vsts-returns-a-400-bad-request)  and track update of VSTS.